# Masking Problems in Illustrator (Is it a bug?)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, mask

All right. So I just want to add a certain pattern (made from objects) to my text for an interesting and satisfying effect. However, when it normally tends to just work with any object.

I just need the green pattern to fill the text like the text is the mask, but for some reason it doesn't seem to work.

[image: I just need the green pattern to fill the text like the text is the mask, but for some reason it doesn't seem to work.]

After creating a mask. And yes the text is outlined and they're all objects.

[image: After creating a mask. And yes the text is outlined and they're all objects.]

When I do it on a simple shape. Is the text too complex for my computer to handle or something?

Maybe the shape the pattern needs to fit in is too complex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you outline text it creates a group, with each letter being its own shape. You can't use a group as a mask, what you need to do is create a compound path from your group. With your outlined text selected:

**Object → Compound Path → Make** (or hit <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd>)

But—**You don't need to outline text to use it as a mask.** Just use your live text as a mask and theres no need for making compound paths or anything and you can still edit your text!